# Pokemon Red/Blue Chaos Edition

Tags: lua, emulation

I'm trying to make a Pokemon Red/Blue Chaos Edition, but like everyone else asking question on this site, I've encountered a bug that I cannot fix. I am using version 2.2.2 (x64) of BizHawk. The error is as follows:

```
NLua.Exceptions.LuaScriptException: [string "main"]:12: invalid arguments to method call
```

https://pastebin.com/pWmByXum

I did some research, and came to the conclusion that it's trying to run line 12 as a function even though I have none.

Answer (score 1):

`rng` is being defined as a local variable *inside* the `if` block. It is therefore not available outside of that block when it is used as an argument to the call on line 12. At that point it would be `nil`. Move the declaration of rng to above the `if` block:

```
local rng = nil
```

Then in both places in fhe `if` block when you assign a value, just write:

```
rng = ...
```

instead of

```
local rng = ...
```

rng will then get assigned a value, but be available outside of the `if` block

Comment: I always seem to overlook the most simple of things. Thank you so much.

Comment: @TheGreatMrBullFrof Sure thing! Upvote/Mark as correct. It helps everyone know that this is resolved